# how to decode bson by java or clojure

Tags: java, clojure, bson

I want to decode a BSON file to a Clojure map.

This is my code:

```
(ns decode
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as cji])
  (:import [org.bson BasicBSONObject BasicBSONEncoder BasicBSONDecoder]))

(defonce encoder (BasicBSONEncoder.))

(defonce decoder (BasicBSONDecoder.))

(defn read-file [file-path]
  (with-open [reader (cji/input-stream file-path)]
    (let [length (.length (clojure.java.io/file file-path))
          buffer (byte-array length)]
      (.read reader buffer 0 length)
      buffer)))


(defn bson2map [^Byte b]
  (->> (.readObject decoder b) (.toMap) (into {})))

(defn read-bson
  [path]
 (clojure.walk/keywordize-keys (bson2map (read-file path))))
```

But when I decode a BSON file like this `(r/read-bson "test.bson")`, it just decodes the first record and I want to decode all of them. The `test.bson` is too big. How do I decode it in fragments?

---

Then I found a class called `LazyBSONDecoder`, wrote some java code and it works, it can decode all of the records.

```
import org.bson.LazyBSONDecoder;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("./_Installation.bson");
        LazyBSONDecoder decoder = new LazyBSONDecoder();
        Object obj;
        int count = 0;
        try {
            do {
                obj = decoder.readObject(in);
                System.out.println(obj);
                count++;
            } while (obj != null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

---

So I changed the Clojure code replacing the `BasicBSONDecoder` for the `LazyBSONDecoder` but it always just decodes the first record.

```
(defonce decoder (LazyBSONDecoder.))

(defn bson2map [^Byte b]
  (do (print (.readObject decoder b))
      (print (.readObject decoder b))
      (print (.readObject decoder b))))
```

Comment: the Java version has a `do`/`while` loop while your Clojure version only call the `readObject` method once.

Comment: @myguidingstar In the last example there are three calls to `.readObject` but according to the OP the first record is returned on all of them.

Comment: @ipaomian Can you provide a sample BSON file to check what the problem is?

Comment: will this help: https://github.com/mrh0057/clj-bson/blob/master/src/clj_bson/core.clj#L17 ?

Comment: @tolitius @juan.facoorro thank you to give me some suggestions,i have solved the problem,the function `bson2map` parame should be a inputStream but no byte-array.[LazyBSONDecoder](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/org/bson/LazyBSONDecoder.java)

Answer (score 0):

please look at this code [LazyBSONDecoder](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/org/bson/LazyBSONDecoder.java)

the function `bson2map` parame should be a inputStream and not a byte-array,if it is byte-array,it will be return a new `ByteArrayInputStream`, so i always get the first record.